# Why do .text segments have different addresses and offsets?

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, executable, clang++

An executable program I built with clang, after viewing it with readelf -SW, shows the following

```
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  ......
  [13] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        0000000000048368 048368 066ae4 00   A  0   0  8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        00000000000afe80 0aee80 189e1c 00  AX  0   0 64
  [15] malloc_hook       PROGBITS        0000000000239c9c 238c9c 000208 00  AX  0   0  2
```

The address and offset of each segment before the .text segment are equal, but from the .text segment onwards these two values start to be unequal.

I tried using objdump -D to see exactly what was between the .text segment and its predecessor, with the following results.

```
   aee44:   049d029e    .inst   0x049d029e ; undefined
   aee48:   00000000    udf #0

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000afe80 <_start>:
   afe80:   d503249f    bti j
   afe84:   d280001d    mov x29, #0x0                       // #0
   afe88:   d280001e    mov x30, #0x0                       // #0
   afe8c:   910003e0    mov x0, sp
   afe90:   14000001    b   afe94 <_start_main>
```

Apparently, immediately after aee48 comes afe80, and I'm puzzled by this, why is this happening?
I also looked at the memory map of the program as it runs, as follows

```
5555555000-5555604000 r--p 00000000 fb:0c 282600
5555604000-5555790000 r-xp 000ae000 fb:0c 282600
5555790000-5555798000 r--p 00239000 fb:0c 282600
5555798000-55557a0000 rw-p 00240000 fb:0c 282600
```

Here too it's even different from the readelf readout, which shows the executable segment at an ae000 offset in the executable, and I don't understand why that's so different.

Comment: Memory mapping happens at page level, which is almost everywhere 4KB or 0x1000. (note how all addresses have three zeroes at the end) 0aee80 is 0xe80 bytes past the start of a page, so your OS has mapped the entire page from the start into memory.

Comment: @Botje: I'm sorry, but to be honest I still don't quite understand what the "ae000" stands for here. Can you explain what exactly this offset refers to? I found some explanation as "If the region was mapped from a file (using mmap), this is the offset in the file where the mapping begins. Does this mean the offset in the file or the offset in the file loaded into memory?

Comment: As your question has already demonstrated, the full file is never mapped into memory sequentially as it is on disk. Instead, the OS has mapped into memory the contents of the file starting from 0xae000 onwards. This is thus "the offset in the file". The final size of that memory range is a bit larger than the size of your text segment; I suppose this is due to rounding up to a multiple of 0x4000 (16kb)

Comment: @Botje: I think I basically understand. Thank you very much!